# win_ros roslaunch error can't find module

Tags: ros, win-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get win_ros running and am having problems (I plan to have some nodes running on a Windows machine due to some hardware only having Windows support, with the main ROS system on Linux).

I followed the instructions on:
win_ros hydro Msvc SDK

Installing all the python packages, and extracting the precompiled SDK and rosdeps to C:\opt, and adding to my path variable.

Right now I'm trying to test the system before attempting any of my own development following the test instructions: I call C:\opt\ros\hydro\x86\setup.bat, and as a test I ran rospack list and all the expected packages show up in the list. However, when I try to run roscore I get:
ImportError: No module named roslaunch
Is there something I have missed in the setup? Is there other scripts I need to run besides C:\opt\ros\hydro\x86\setup.bat

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103301/win_ros-roslaunch-error-can%27t-find-module/) by [Chimpien](https://answers.ros.org/users/9036/chimpien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-11-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yeongil Choe](https://answers.ros.org/users/4499/yeongil-choe/) on 2013-11-20**:
I tried to reproduce your situation on clean pc installed Windows 7, but couldn't reproduce it. Check PYTHONPATH after call c:/opt/ros/hydro/x86/setup.bat like 'echo %PYTHONPATH%' on Windows command prompt, and check you can import roslaunch via command line of python client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found the issue in that another piece of software installed on my system (it's a work build so I didn't install it myself) used python within it and appeared earlier in the path so was running Python 2.6.2 instead of 2.7 meaning all the paths were wrong. Having shifted python27 to the beginning of PATH roscore is now running. Thanks for your speedy reply.

---

Originally posted by [Chimpien](https://answers.ros.org/users/9036/chimpien/) with karma: 16 on 2013-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0